# How to use <Video></Video> in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i am trying to make Video as my backgroud for my WebForm in visual studio 2010 ultimate but when i use  it always says to me that validation (xhtml 1.0 transitional) element 'video' is not supported so how can i fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a code-section to show others how you are attempting to use it at the moment, and describe what is not. You will benefit greatly by reading the introduction on how to ask good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use windows media player to play video in visual studio 2010. it's hard to explain with words so go to this video you can see how you can add video in visual studio 2010. [here](https://youtu.be/PLQtUxoX0zw)

Comment: Hi, i am using VS2010 ultimate and i dont have in my tool box components

Comment: can you add screenshot?